# Tableau: How to divide two table calculations?

Tags: tableau-api

I have these calculated measures which I use within a tool tip as table calculations

```
[alert_count_by_action] = total([distinct_alerts]) compute using day
[alert_count_all] = total(distinct alerts]) compute using table across
```

When I mouse over an action name colored widget type I can see that the `[alert_count_by_action]` and `[alert_count_all]` are producing the correct values. What I would like to do is to compute a percent by dividing `[alert_count_by_action] / [alert_count_all]` which I will call `[alerts_by_action_percent_overall]`. This is not working at all despite trying every combination available on the table calculation options within the Marks card.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: stacked bar chart of alerts by action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the attached workbook, I can only suggest to check the partitioning of your % calculation. Because both components of the fraction are themselves table calculations, they can be partitioned separately (i.e. "compute using" options).
There should be a combo-box in the 'Edit table calculation' dialog that selects which component is being configured.
Maybe you have configured one part, but not other?

Comment: I have played with the partitioning of the % calculation with no success.

Comment: I changed the formula for the `[alert_count_by_action]` to `WINDOW_SUM( count([Alert ID]),FIRST(),LAST())` as I understand now that the table functions are only acting on the data already in the table. Oddly though I had to replace the `[alerts_by_action_percent_overall]` with a new calculated field with same formula. Then when I added it to the tooltip, I was able to choose `[alert_count_by_action]` as the calculated field for it to act on.